# How to find inverse of a power series?

Tags: sequences-and-series, derivatives, power-series

In a textbook I found this expansion

$$
\begin{align}
\frac1{\sin(z)}
&=\frac1z\frac{z}{\sin(z)}\\
&=\frac1z\left(1-\frac{z^2}{3!}+\frac{z^4}{5!}-\frac{z^6}{7!}+\cdots\right)^{-1}\\
&=\frac1z\left(1+\frac{z^2}{6}+\frac{7z^4}{360}+\frac{31z^6}{15120}+\cdots\right)\\
&=\frac1z+\frac{z}{6}+\frac{7z^3}{360}+\frac{31z^5}{15120}+\cdots
\end{align}
$$

and I am unsure of how we got $\displaystyle \frac1z\left(1+\frac{z^2}{6}+\frac{7z^4}{360}+\frac{31z^6}{15120}+\cdots\right)$ from $\displaystyle\frac1z\left(1-\frac{z^2}{3!}+\frac{z^4}{5!}-\frac{z^6}{7!}+\cdots\right)^{-1}$.

In general if we have

$$
f(x)=a_0+a_1+a_2 x^2+a_3x^3+...
$$

then we wanted to write

$$
\frac{1}{f(x)}=b_0+b_1+b_2 x^2+b_3x^3+...
$$

my question is how are the values of $b_n$ determined?

Comment: Just mechanical division / synthetic division, I guess.

Comment: Is your query solved ?

Comment: There is a formula to get the inverse of $f$ directly but I forgot the detail.